# (viewDidLoad.subscribe) events are worked one time in each of visited tab only

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have a code:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, Nav, App, Tabs} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})

export class TabsPage {
  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;
  
  app: App;

 constructor(app:App, nav: Nav) {
    this.app = app;

    console.log('=======================');
    this.app.viewDidLoad.subscribe((view) => {
      console.log(view.instance.constructor.name);
    });
  }
}
```

at first I get:

```
=======================
TabsPage
HomePage
```

when I navigate other tab:

```
AboutPage
```

And other tab:

```
ContactPage
```

but now I back on same tabs and events stopped to work, why? 
Help please

Angular have similar module {Router} from '@angular/router'; and there are all good, for example:

```
   router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url == '/notes') {
      }
    });
```

navigatin for child routes work always.
How to make to work Ionic like that?

Comment: Which event did you mean?

Comment: @Sampath, viewDidLoad.subscribe i suppose. Every time when I click on some tab, I need to get info about current tab in tabs.ts

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? Please also notice that using the name of the component won't work when using the `--prod` flag since they're all minified/uglified. Please let us know what you're trying to achieve, so we can see how that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

*.html*

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

*.ts*

```
export class TabsPage {

@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.tabRef.select(2);
 }

}
```

Here you can see all the [**methods and properties**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/).

Comment: it just redirects me to last tab.

Comment: This is just an example.please see the doc and select the method what you need.